# Reference group of variables from one file to another in shell

Tags: shell, variables, parameter-passing

I didn't see anything even close to this use case, so I am unsure how this would look in shell scripting.  Essentially I have a bunch of template shell scripts where the only difference in the files is a group of 4 variables.  I would like to create another file for these variables like this:

```
# Group 1
Var 1 = A
Var 2 = B
Var 3 = C
Var 4 = D

# Group 2
Var 1 = F
Var 2 = G
Var 3 = H
Var 4 = I
```

etc.  Then I would want to use one shell script as a template and pass in a parameter.  Such as ./script.sh group2.  The script would use this parameter, go off to the input file and determine the group of variables to use for the rest of the script.  Is this possible?  What would be the proper syntax for this?

UPDATE:

An idea I had was something like this:

```
SITE="$1"
VIP="Source ../conf/${$1.VIP}"
DMN1="Source ../conf/${$1.VAR1}"
DMN2="Source ../conf/${$1.VAR2}"
DMN3="Source ../conf/${$1.VAR3}"
```

The idea is that when I run the script, I run ./script.sh ABC
From this, the script will use ABC as the site, then from the config file, reference the variable labeled ABC.VIP to ABC.DMN3.  In the config file, it would read ABC.VIP="abcvip".  Would this not alleviate my problem?  I am assuming something like this would work, but I am unsure on the syntax of it all.  Mostly the linking to a source variable reference.

Comment: If you have defined your variable groups required in different files, then your script you can source the file like normal profile file. Like add "source group_1" in your script.sh

Comment: Well in doing that, I wouldn't really be adding any real benefit.  I was hoping to be able to have one config file of variables and the generic script that excepts parameter to choose which group to use from the config file.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve with a simple function creation, which indirectly works as the above case.

```
######### Make this as a source file #### 
group_1()
{
Var1=A
Var2=B
Var3=C
Var4=D
}

group_2()
{
Var1=F
Var2=G
Var3=H
Var4=I
}
###################
```

Create the above content in a file and create another file where you can call the particular variables, like below

```
if [[ target == "group_1" ]]
  then
    group_1
    echo $Var1
  else
    group_2
  echo $Var1
fi
```

Hope this will solve your problem